# System.InvalidOperationException - No error details

Tags: vb.net

A VB.NET app is working on XP, but not in Win 7.  User executes the program and it immediate dies with "Stopped Working".  A Report.wer file was created and there's no detailed reason other than "System.InvalidOperationException".

How do I get it to tell me more.  I put a messagebox in the form load, but it didn't get that far.

Comment: Does the IDE not break on the exception?

Comment: @lee-m It doesn't fail in WinXP (my development environment).  Another programmer with Win 7 says it works in the debugger and fails with the same error when running the executable.

Comment: @lee-m I got it working by debugging it in Win 7.  I found out which library I didn't include.  I have the library on my development PC, but it wasn't included in the setup.exe.  On the other PC, it didn't exist and it was easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this exception thrown when attempting to run a Windows Forms applications when some of the controls used by the application are defined in a separate assembly which is not present on the machine you're trying to run it on.